# Trying to run a program in C

Tags: c

Can someone help me to run this program? I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    double Cateto1;
    double Cateto2;
    double hipotenusa;

    printf("dame el primer cateto: ");
    scanf("%1f", Cateto1);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("dame el segundo cateto: ");
    scanf("%1f", &Cateto2);
    fflush(stdout);

    hipotenusa = sqrt ((Cateto1*Cateto1)+(Cateto2*Cateto2));

    printf("hipotenusa= %2f",hipotenusa);
    system("pause");
}
```

I can build it but I can't run it... it gives me:

> RUN FAILED (exit value -1.073.741.790, total time: 17s)

Comment: Why your `main` doesn't return a thing?

Comment: what is your platform? how do you run it?

Comment: Have you turned on all compiler warnings?  I get `10:26: warning: variable 'Cateto1' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
            scanf("%1f", Cateto1);`

Comment: You should move up  `fflush(stdout)` to before the `scanf` to make sure the text is displayed *before* scanning for input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
scanf("%lf", Cateto1);
        ↑    ↑
        |    You are missing a '&' character here
        The width specifier for doubles is l, not 1
```

The first argument to scanf must be `"%lf"` (as the letter L) to specify that the corresponding output variable is a pointer to double instead of a float. `'1'` (One) has no meaning for scanf.

The second argument to scanf here is expected to be a pointer to double, and you're giving it a double instead.
I suppose it is a simple typo since you got it right the second time.

Comment: I'm just kidding :D The upvotes have nothing to do with it :) And you're welcome

Comment: Since you have that beautiful ↑ I added another for the format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the mistake:

```
scanf("%1f", Cateto1);
```

Change it to:

```
scanf("%1f", &Cateto1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors:

- The syntax of the `scanf` expression was wrong: "%1f" should be "%lf"
- You need to pass the address of `Cateto1` (`&Cateto1`) to `scanf`
- You don't need the `fflush`
- You don't need the `system` call

Here's the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    double Cateto1;
    double Cateto2;
    double hipotenusa;

    printf("dame el primer cateto: ");
    scanf("%lf", &Cateto1);

    printf("dame el segundo cateto: ");
    scanf("%lf", &Cateto2);

    hipotenusa = sqrt ((Cateto1*Cateto1)+(Cateto2*Cateto2));

    printf("hipotenusa= %2f\n",hipotenusa);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explicitly said what they are rather than me trying to do a mental diff to spot the difference. Are you saying the system pause has caused the error?

Comment: I put the code in first and then added the explanation to beat the gun ;-)

Comment: @ct_ hehe...I can see why you'd do that, but as I saw it, it was too early

Answer (score 0):

There is an Error in your code. Instead of

```
scanf("%1f", Cateto1);
```

you should write:

```
scanf("%1f", &Cateto1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Mistake

```
scanf("%1f", &Cateto1); // '&' was missing in all scanf statements
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             #include <stdio.h>

             #include <math.h>

            int main(void) 
            {

               double Cateto1;

               double Cateto2;

               double hipotenusa;

               printf("dame el primer cateto: ");

               scanf("%lf", &Cateto1);

               //fflush(stdout);

               printf("dame el segundo cateto: ");

               scanf("%lf", &Cateto2);

               //fflush(stdout);

               hipotenusa = sqrt ((Cateto1*Cateto1)+(Cateto2*Cateto2));

               printf("hipotenusa= %2f\n",hipotenusa);

               //system("pause");

               return 0;

         }
```