# scanf can only read 3 characters into a 5 position char array

Tags: c++, c

Compiler : Gcc Linux 32-bit

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[5];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%c",&a[i]);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%c",a[i]);
}
```

Why does this array `a` accepts only three characters even though I have specified it to take 5 characters?  If I input integers it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf()` is reading the newlines. If you entered `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each one, then `a` would contain `{'a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 'c'}`, and the final `'\n'` would not be read.

Answer (score 3):

This is because newline character (`\n` on Unix/Linux) is left behind by `scanf()` for the next call of `scanf()` (in this case). Change `scanf("%c",&a[i]);` to

```
scanf(" %c",&a[i]);  
       ↑
   space before specifier
```

When putting a space before `%c`, `scanf()` skips any number of white-space characters in the input.

Comment: Why this is not when inputting integers in same way?

Comment: Because a newline is not an integer, it's a character.

Comment: @InsaneCoder because an integer is not a character (at least conceptually). You see, the use of `scanf()` is not intuitive. **Stay far away from this crappy function.** Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: @SirDarious; How did you do that?

Comment: @haccks simple unicode arrow (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)) got a post of mine edited to have one (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19297566/393701) felt like spreading the joy :P

Comment: @InsaneCoder: Since %d is intended to read a number, it's specified to skip any leading whitespace. Since %c is intended to support reading characters (and you may be interested in whitespace characters) it doesn't skip them.

Comment: @SirDarius; I tried to print this arrow on MS-WIN7 by pressing   Alt + 2191 and I am getting `Å` :(

Comment: @Paul Griffiths  `\n` is an `int` and so it is an integer.  Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof('\n'))`.  OTOH `\n` is not a _digit_ as isdigit('\n') returns 0.  Had OP input "1\n2\n3\n", The same mysterious "3 characters" would have occurred.

Comment: @chux: A character constant has type `int`, sure, and `char` is also an integral type. This does not make integers and characters equivalent, as this example clearly shows, and as common usage dictates. Whether your hypothetical input would give the same results is going to depend on whether and how the shell escapes those characters.

Comment: @chux: Actually, not even the shell, since this is using `scanf()`. I'd be amazed if you'd find a C implementation that converted the typed in `'\'` and `'n'` characters to a newline, that would be very unusual behavior.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths  The "1\n2\n3\n" is meant to imply 6 keyboard entries: 1, enter, 2, enter, 3, enter and not 9 staring with 1, \, n, ...  Sorry if this was confusing.  It was meant to be like your answer, but with digits rather than letters to illustrate OP's issues are not "newline" being a integer or not, but one as explained in your post.

Comment: @chux: Aha, sorry, totally misunderstood what you were saying with that.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is consumed by `scanf()` that's why the rest 2 characters are not taken.

Add a leading space before `%c`

**Change to:**

```
scanf(" %c", &a[i]);
```

Comment: "Note that Enter is equivalent to \n in C" - well, on 5% of the world's computers anyway. And the rest, 95%, runs Windows.

Comment: LOL I also run Windows & I love it :P

Comment: @H2CO3 In factoring "world's computers", you may want to consider the billion embedded processors sold each year.  C is very popular there.

Comment: @chux Yay, fair enough. The point is, Windows is (unfortunately) in an  overwhelming majority, and it denotes newlines with the terrible `\r\n` character sequence. Furthermore, the C standard doesn't define what the newline character should be. Take this two, and the assertion "Note that Enter is equivalent to `\n` in C" is just **horribly wrong.**

Comment: @Umer Farooq  Note: Typically Windows keyboard interfaces creates 2 `char`, `\r` and `\n` when the _Enter_ is pressed.  As `stdin` is usually in "text" mode, it changes this pair into a `\n`.  Using `freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin)`, putting `stdin` in "binary" mode, one can readily see _Enter_ is _not_ always equivalent to `\n`'.

Comment: @H2CO3 I would say C _does_ define the newline character `\n` as "(new line) Moves the active position to the initial position of the next line."  I think you mean something closer to C does not define the value of `\n` nor does C define what an _enter_ key should do.  In any case, this answer with "\n is consumed by scanf() that's why the rest 2 characters are not taken." is at best confusing, at worst - incorrect.

Comment: @chux Yes, that's exact. (However, I', not sure if "new line" is really `\n` -- on some systems, `\n` only moves the cursor one line down, and a carriage return `\r` is necessary to put it back to the starting position.)